# Proof that the the set $f^{-1}([0,\infty))$ is a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds

I have been reading Munkres's book Analysis on Manifolds. The proof of the following theorem (theorem 24.4 on page 207) is not hard but I can't think of a way to motivate it.

> Theorem 24.4. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f: \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^r$. Let $M$ be the set of points $x$ for which $f(x)=0$; let $N$ be the set of points for which $f(x) \geq 0$. Suppose $M$ is non-empty and $D f(x)$ has rank 1 at each point of $M$. Then $N$ is an $n$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\partial N=M$.

> Proof. Suppose first that $\mathbf{p}$ is a point of $N$ such that $f(\mathbf{p})>0$. Let $U$ be the open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting of all points $x$ for which $f(x)>0$; let $\alpha: U \rightarrow U$ be the identity map. Then $\alpha$ is (trivially) a coordinate patch on $N$ about $\mathbf{p}$ whose domain is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Now suppose that $f(p)=0$. Since $D f(p)$ is non-zero, at least one of the partial derivatives $D_i f(\mathbf{p})$ is non-zero. Suppose $D_n f(\mathbf{p}) \neq 0$. Define $F: \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ by the equation $F(\mathbb{x})=\left(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, f(\mathbf{x})\right)$. Then
> $$
> D F=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
> I_{n-1} & 0 \\
> * & D_n f
> \end{array}\right],
> $$
> so that $D F(\mathbf{p})$ is non-singular. It follows that $F$ is a diffeomorphism of a neighborhood $A$ of $\mathbb{p}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with an open set $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore, $F$ carries the open set $A \cap N$ of $N$ onto the open set $B \cap \mathbb H^n$ of $H^n$, since $x \in N$ if and only if $f(x) \geq 0$. It also carries $A \cap M$ onto $B \cap \partial \mathbb H^n$, since $x \in M$ if and only if $f(x)=0$. Then $F^{-1}: B \cap \mathbb{H}^n \rightarrow A \cap N$ is the required coordinate patch on N.

Here, $\mathbb{H}^k$ is the upper of plane of $\mathbb R^k$. Munkres defined coordinate patches to be those maps $\alpha:U\to V$, where $U$ can be open either in $\mathbb R^k$ or $\mathbb{H}^k$.

In this proof, why would one define such a map $F(\mathbf{x})=\left(x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}, f(\mathbf{x})\right)$? I can't come up with an adequate motivation for this step.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks in advance!